# Why is my contract not successfully deploying in Remix?

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Todo {

    struct TODO {
        string text;
        bool completed;
        address owner;
    }

    TODO[] public todos;

    function create(string memory _text, bool _completed) public {
        todos.push(TODO(_text, _completed, msg.sender));

    }

    constructor() {
        TODO storage todo = todos[0];
        todo.owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function get(uint _index) public view returns(string memory, bool, address) {
        TODO storage todo = todos[_index];
        return(todo.text, todo. completed, todo.owner);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `todos` have no element in it , so accessing an ghost element will failed the deployment

Comment: How can I initialize the owner variable to as the deployer of the contract using constructor??

Comment: @Yannick ,  initialize a todo with owner set to msg.sender, then push your todo into todos

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is remove your constructor, it's not needed. Then it will compile, deploy an run.

Comment: im trying to initialize the owner variable using constructor upon deployment...how do I do that?